# Android MediaPlayer2 discards HTTP headers?

Tags: android, media-player, exoplayer

I create `UrlMediaItem` and add some headers:

```java
MediaItem mi = new UriMediaItem.Builder(Uri.parse(url), tinode.getRequestHeaders(), null).build();
Log.i(TAG, "Media URL=" + ((UriMediaItem)mi).getUri());
Log.i(TAG, "Headers=" + ((UriMediaItem)mi).getUriHeaders());
```

The logging is just to show that it works. Here is the logcat with correct headers added:

```
2022-11-26 16:45:10.740 MessagesAdapter I Media URL=http://10.0.2.2:6060/v0/file/s/xY-I5Gegl6A.webm
2022-11-26 16:45:10.740 MessagesAdapter I Headers = {X-Tinode-Auth=Token 00000000000000000000, User-Agent=Tindroid/0.20.8-10-gbf7f8ab4 (Android 12; en_US); tindroid/0.20.8-10-gbf7f8ab4, X-Tinode-APIKey=AQEAAAABAAD_rAp4DJh05a1HAwFT3A6K}
```

But the server receives the request with no headers!

```
GET /v0/file/s/xY-I5Gegl6A.webm HTTP/1.1
Host: 10.0.2.2:6060
Accept-Encoding: identity
Connection: Keep-Alive
Icy-Metadata: 1
User-Agent: MediaPlayer2/0.20.8-10-gbf7f8ab4 (Linux;Android 12) ExoPlayerLib/2.10.4
```

If this my bug or Android bug? I can kind of understand why it replaces my `User-Agent` with its own, but stripping `X-Tinode-Auth` and `X-Tinode-APIKey` is uncool.

Comment: Are you sure it is not just that the server is not including the authentication headers in it's logging - have you a Wireshark or similar capture to see the full message that the server receives? It's a common security measure to not include authentication info in server logging.

Comment: I'm pretty sure it's Android. It's actually a bug/mis-feature in Android. It even kind of mentioned in the docs. The issue here is that `MediaPlayer` runs in a separate process. The `UriMediaItem` is sent to the player through IPC. Android serializes all subclasses of `MediaItem` as base class (I have no idea what they were smoking). It says so in the docs. So essentially, all data including HTTP headers which are present in `UrlMediaItem` but not in `MediaItem `are lost by design. `UriMediaItem` is not my class. It's a part of the spec.